# Realtek RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter Not connecting, keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless, usb

Info: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7qJ7BYBy

Ive got output from lsusb, lsmod, ifconfig and syslog there

What happens is that it can detect wireless networks but can't connect to them. It just keeps asking for the wifi password. I've tried both WEP and WPA2 Personal, both no luck.

This wifi device is a wifi dongle that seems to be using a Realtek chip as you can see from lsusb output. I really have no idea what's wrong with it because it is working fine in other OS. But I'd really like to use linux so I'm trying to get this to work.

Hope someone can help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running? lsb_release -d.

Comment: @chili555 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated rtl8192xx driver available. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
```

Reboot and tell us if the behavior has improved.

Comment: Im using quantal and the graphics messed up after installing this. Im using an Intel GPU

Comment: Quantal? Your response above says 12.04, not 12.10. "@chili555 12.04 LTS"

Comment: Im sorry, I am trying the dongle in 2 Ubuntu versions just to be sure. Latest Linux Mint (Nadia?) and Ubuntu quantal.

Comment: In Quantal, remove the incorrect package: sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic; install the correct one: sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic.